# Error in vmware player installation (processor type not supported)

Tags: installation, vmware-workstation

I am trying to install Vmware workstation 12.5.0-4352439 and i got this error:

[image]

I am using samsung np300e5c (Intel (R) core (TM)i5-3210M, x64 based processor, 4gb, windows 10 x86 bit).

Can anyone help me identifying the issue. Or what should i do to fix this problem?

Comment: Did you try Google? Search for *vmware workstation requirements*. And there's no such thing as *Windows 10 x86 bit*, because there is no such thing as *x86 bit*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VMware Player 12 is a 64-bit application. It cannot be installed on a 32-bit operating system. VMware Player hasn't supported 32-bit operating systems since VMware Player 6.

See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1004891/675327) for more detailed information.